# How to access Logs of Pods in Kubernetes after its deletion

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

We have CentOS based infra for kubernetes and also using Openshift on top of tis. We have terminated a pod and now its not visible on master controller any more. However we are willing to analyze its logs.Can we still access its logs?How ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Containers together with its logs get deleted when you issue a `kubectl delete pod <pod-name>`. You can use something like [Fluentd](https://www.fluentd.org/) or [logspout](https://github.com/gliderlabs/logspout) to pipe your logs to say an [ELK](https://www.elastic.co/elk-stack) or an [EFK](https://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/docker-logging-efk-compose) stack.

Comment: How do you know FluentD processed all logs before the files were deleted?

Comment: They are usually streamed real time and assuming you don't have network/capacity issues, they would make it to its final destination. So whatever you delete, should be already in something like elastic search.

Comment: Thanks! I'll see what I can do to ensure I get no network or capacity issues

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the container is removed (docker rm) once the `kubectl delete` of the pod is done and the log files are gone. One way I can think of is using [fluentd](https://www.fluentd.org/why) or something similar for log aggregation.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize containers got deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the Kubernetes Dashboard, you can access logs for deleted/completed pods in the desired namespace.

Comment: `kubectl get events | grep pod-name` just in case Dashboard is not there or when there is no access to Dashboard. But, not sure how long the events are retained. So, it's always better to use a log aggregator.

Comment: Also, in the Dashboard those are events and not logs in the namespace. The application logs are not visible there. The OP was about logs and not events.

Comment: we are using prometheus  and DataDog to collect logs data