# How to see the history in Pod Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I use this `kubectl` to deploy a pod with the image nginx:

```
kubectl create deployment --image=<image-name-1.0> image-app
```

Now I want to update this pod with `image=<image-name-2.0>` and run this command:

```
kubectl create deployment --image=<image-name-2.0> image-app
```

My question is: will the old pod log be updated after updating with image-name-2.0?

Can I see all history logs? I mean the both of them.

Answer (score 0):

To be precise, there isn't a "pod log" but container log, and you can use `kubectl logs --previous <pod name> -c <container name>` to retrieve logs from a previous container.

A side note to update image, you can `kubectl set image deployment/<name> <container name>=<image repo:tag>`

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you can't update your existing deployment using `kubectl create deployment` because you will get error like:

```
error: failed to create deployment: deployments.apps "image-app" already exists
```

You should use `kubectl set image` command as presented in [this example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#updating-a-deployment), in your case:

```
kubectl set image deployment/image-app <container-name>=<image>:<tag>
```

Updating the deployment means that pods with an old version (in your case `image-name-1.0`) will be terminated and new pods (with `image-name-2.0`) will be created. For more details about how a deployment updating process works I'd suggest reading [this article](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/).

It means that you can't fetch logs from pods with older image version using `kubectl logs` command as these pods will no longer exist.

Keep in mind that `kubectl logs --previous <pod-name> -c <container-name>` command is getting logs from previous instance of the container **within the same pod**. If the pod is terminated (this is what happens during deployment update) logs are lost.

*What to do with this?*

You may try getting logs directly from the nodes as [presented in this example from the Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#logging-at-the-node-level) but log files from deleted pods might be deleted as well - depending which container runtime and Kubernetes cluster solution did you use.

The best option is to implement a [central log management system](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#cluster-level-logging-architectures). Check [this answer about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52580830/how-to-access-logs-of-pods-in-kubernetes-after-its-deletion/52583476#52583476).